# Argument mismatch and out of range for a function.

Tags: java, date

I have a simple function which predicts number of seconds elapsed based on a particular format, say when will XXXX seconds complete if calculating from a certain date. The function is as follows:

```
public static void secondsToNotify(long seconds, String D){
        Date Dt = Convert(D); 
        Calendar Cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        Cal.setTime(Dt); 
        secondsSpecial = secondsInterval*(1+(seconds/secondsInterval)); 
        Cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) secondsSpecial);

        dateSecondsReg = Cal.getTime(); 
        System.out.println(""+dateSecondsReg);
        System.out.println(""+secondsSpecial);


    }
```

I call this function like:

```
public static void main(){
        secondsToNotify(2682810000, "1929-01-02"); 
    }
```

The compiler gives me a error message at the function call on the first argument that is 2682810000, which reads: **The literal 2682810000 of type int is out of range**. However as an argument I accept a long. I know I am wrong somewhere, but I am not able to know.

Comment: Append a `L`. `secondsToNotify(2682810000L, "1929-01-02");`. _"An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int."_

Comment: I am so Dumb, however I would want to know what does appending L do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
secondsToNotify(2682810000l, "1929-01-02");
```

or

```
secondsToNotify(2682810000L, "1929-01-02");
```

instead of

```
secondsToNotify(2682810000, "1929-01-02");
```

EDit : Better to use `L` since some times `l` may cause confusion with `1`

Comment: What does appending L do? Does it speak for itself and say hey compiler mate, I am a Long?

Comment: @AstralProjection that is the way we use Long in `Java` else that is like an `int`

Comment: Note that its not recommented to use the `l` (lower case), always prefer `L`.

Comment: @ZouZou yes It is better to use `L`

Comment: `l` (ell) is not recommended since it can be confused with the number `1` but it's allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable guidance

Answer (score 1):

From [JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Add `L` at the end of the number, like so `2682810000L`.